# Running kafka-console-producer.sh to another server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have installed Apache Kafka on my centos server.  I am simply trying to write a message to a topic on another server.  So after installing, I did NOT start the zookeeper or the Kafka server, but simply typed in the command:

```
echo testing | ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxx.yyy.com:2181 --topic topicx
```

I am able to ping xxx.yyy.com from my server.  When I run this, I get this error:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic cds_organization with key: null, value: 7 bytes with error:
>  (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>       org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topicx not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

So in this scenario, do I still need to start the zookeeper and/or kafka server?

Comment: "./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxx.yyy.com:2181 --topic topicx"  Have you tried running this command alone without "echo"

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: Please check whether topic is existed or not by using kafka-topics.sh command. ./kakfa-topics.sh --zookeeper host:port --list

Comment: Also please check auto.create.topis.enable is set to true or false in broker configuration

Comment: The topic DOES come up when I run kafka-topics.sh with the host:port.  I enabled auto.create.topics.enable=true, but it made no difference.

Comment: "kafka-console-producer --broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092 --topic topicx" try producing this way

Comment: @GokulPotluri `0.0.0.0` isn't a real address... That shouldn't work

Comment: you are able to ping server, but what about topic? is that exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working.  The issue was that the Kafka server which had the topic I was trying to write to was on version 0.8.2.1, and I had installed the latest version.  When I installed the same version, kafka-console-producer.sh worked fine WITHOUT having to start either zookeeper or the local Kafka server.

Answer (score 1):

"**./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxx.yyy.com:2181 --topic topicx**", your commad, missed this part,  is your broker listening on PORT 2181, normally it will be 9092.  
Change commad to "**./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxx.yyy.com:9092 --topic topicx**" and try again

Comment: Yes, it IS listening on 2181, when I run kafka-topics with 2181, it shows the topic:

./kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic topicx --zookeeper xxx.yyy.com:2181 

Output is:

Topic:topicx PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: topicx Partition: 0 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1 Isr: 1

Comment: @hamayoun No... `kafka-topics` uses `--zookeeper`. This **is not** a broker that needs to be listed via `--broker-list`. These are ideally completely different machines.

Answer (score 0):

> I did NOT start the zookeeper or the Kafka server, but simply typed in the command:

If neither is running, then no command you listed should work.

> do I still need to start the zookeeper and/or kafka server

Yes, you will need both to be running, but don't need to be on the same machines.

---

As mentioned, Kafka's default port is 9092. Zookeeper is 2181. It seems you have mixed them.

Describing topics (`kafka-topics`) command is done via Zookeeper **only** ([up until Kafka 2.2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-377%3A+TopicCommand+to+use+AdminClient)).

To produce, you should to use *the Kafka host & port* (as of Kafka 0.9).

Comment: I have started both zookeeper and kafka on my server.  The result when I try and run "echo testing | ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list xxx.yyy.com:2181 --topic topicx" is still the same, even when I change the port to 9092

Comment: Is `xxx.yyy.com:9092`  running Kafka? Did you correctly establish the `advertised.listeners` property of Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this for my Springboot applications by adding a separate spring-kafka dependency with the version matching the kafka server version.